# Current position with Dynamixel servomotor AX12

Tags: dynamixel, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi friends

I am working with Dynamixel servomotor A12 and ROS fuerte, I need to get a pan and tilt and when I do transforms I need to know which is the current position of 2 motors.

I don't know if the easiest way is using topics or services, please can you help me? I have looking for information and reading wiki ros but I have not found an explain.

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/211628/current-position-with-dynamixel-servomotor-ax12/) by [Rookie92](https://answers.ros.org/users/18371/rookie92/) on ROS Answers with karma: 47 on 2015-06-18

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use the arbotix or dynamixel_motor package to control the servos. They publish the positions and other stuff to some topic of type sensor_msgs/JointState or dynamixel_msgs/JointState, depending on the package.

---

Originally posted by [Girts L](https://answers.ros.org/users/3081/girts-l/) with karma: 196 on 2015-07-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0